# What is my apple orchard soil type?

Tags: soil, apples, soil-test

It's about three month that I have bought this orchard.
I have have done Bottle test on my orchard soil. But my test results did not look  like what I have seen in internet. So I decided to post my pictures here to get help. I can't figure out percentage of clay/silt/sand from this bottle test. Maybe It's all clay with ab little bit of sand.
From the crack is in my soil I expect it's clay. 
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The water in the bottle test is almost transparent, so the proportion of clay cannot be significant otherwise the water would remain murky for a long time - unless you have had the bottle standing for a couple of weeks or put in in a centrifuge... It is true that significant sand component would not lead to cracks in dry soil, so this indicates a predominantly silty soil, perhaps with some sand and clay but with these in minor proportions.

Comment: Thanks for help, These picture have been taken about 24 hours after bottle shake. So if it's mostly silt I am really happy about that, If you have any recommendation for soil improvement I really appreciate that. I want to apply about 10 cm of manure layer on my soil but some people say it will kill your tree. And Also I don't know I can apply that right now or wait for fall.